# Difference between dates

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Difference between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533909/difference-between-dates)
>   [How to calculate the date difference between 2 dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-date-difference-between-2-dates-using-php)

So, I have two dates. For instance, `2010-09-24` and `2010-09-25`. I want to check if between those two dates the difference is 1 day.

I don't need to get a value of `86400` which means one day in seconds.

Don't forget that it can be 28, 28, 29, 30, 31 days in month.

Thanks.

What I have right now, but it doesn't work when there is difference between months:

```
$strto = strtotime($date);
$d1 = date('d', $strto);
$d2 = date('d', time());
echo $d2- $d1;
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: @SilentGhost : i will edit in one sec, please wait.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533909/difference-between-dates) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Difference+between+dates+php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the number of seconds in between

```
echo abs(strtotime('2010-09-24') - strtotime('2010-09-25'));
```

Comment: Just watch out in case the date range encompasses the change for daylight savings, because then your seconds result won't be a whole number of days

Comment: @Mark Baker : What do you mean?

Comment: echo abs(strtotime('2010-09-24') - strtotime('2010-09-25')); would normally return 86400; but if the daylight savings began or ended on '2010-09-24', then you'd get a return value of 82800 or 90000 depending on whether the clocks were going forward or back (assumption of 1hr and a timezone that implements daylight saving). To avoid problems, you can set date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); before doing the calculation, and set it back again afterwards, because GMT is constant through the year (no daylight saving).

Comment: @Mark Baker: Thank you. I'll surely do.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `date('d'...` which returns the day of the month?

`strtotime` will create a UNIX-timestamp which is exactly what `time()` returns, so `abs(time() - strtotime($date))` should already do the job. This way you don't have to worry how many days a month has as you're only working with timestamps.

This will get you the number of (complete) days:

```
floor( abs(time() - strtotime($date)) / 86400 )
```

Comment: No it won't do the job, because `$date` and `time()` can have only, for example, 5 seconds.

Comment: Then I didn't get your question as well as what you mean by "can have only 5 seconds" ... how can `time()` "have 5 seconds" ??? If the return value is bothering you, use `floor(value/86400)` to get the number of days instead of seconds.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the strtotime function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the day value - (eg `date('d', ...)`) - leave it as an integer (the result of `strtotime()`).  *Then* subtract those dates, and then get the `floor(difference / 86400)`.

Like so:

```
$dt = strtotime($date);
echo floor(abs(time() - $dt) / 86400);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this nicely with the DateTime class if you have PHP 5.3:

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2010-09-25');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2010-09-26');

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

$intervaldays = (int) $interval->format('%R%d'); // %R signs the result +/-
```

This is probably less efficient than using strtotime methods, but it is very readable.